# different results in calculating recall and precision from two different methods

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, grid-search, precision-recall

As per the code below, I am calculating the recall and precision scores for a specific classifier

```
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=20)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
pred=clf.predict(X_test)
precision_recall_fscore_support(y_test, pred, average='micro' or, 'weighted', or, 'macro', or 'none')
```

Then the result would be

```
(0.8861803737814977, 0.8714028776978417, 0.8736586610015085, None)
(0.8714028776978417, 0.8714028776978417, 0.8714028776978417, None)
(0.8576684989847967, 0.883843537414966, 0.8649539913120651, None)

(array([0.95433071, 0.76100629]),
 array([0.84166667, 0.92602041]),
array([0.89446494, 0.83544304]),
array([720, 392]))
```

But if I calculate them by using

```
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier()
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
param_grid = {'n_estimators':range(20,23)}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid, scoring=scorers, refit=recall_score,

                       cv=skf, return_train_score=True, n_jobs=-1)
results = pd.DataFrame(grid_search_clf.cv_results_)
```

Then I will get the following
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBMAM.jpg)

You can see that the mean recall and precision score is very different from the one that was calculated in previous step while the same data with the same parameter has been applied to both. I was wondering if anyone can help me what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the metrics are calculated on different things.

```
precision_recall_fscore_support(y_test, pred)
```

Shows the value of the metric on the test data.

But when you use GridSearchCV, train data is split into train and test following the defined cv and metrics are calculated on this test data, which is a subset of train data. And then the metrics are averaged over folds.